# jQuery & highcharts & Math prototype ?

Tags: jquery, prototype, highcharts

Consider this:

```
Math.__proto__.eps=1e-16;

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    //...
    });
});
```

Quite strangely this happens:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object 1e-16 has no method 'push'

This has something to do with jQuery way of handling prototypes and binding members/functions. How should i rewrite my .eps property so that jQuery won't complain?
(i don't think it has anything to do with Highcharts, it's just the way i found it happens)

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Math` is an instance of `Object` so I think you mean to assign directly to that instance, ie.

```
Math.eps=1e-16;
```

Assigning to it's prototype is assigning to `Object` which can understandably cause side effects.

Comment: No idea. I don't see any proof that it actually is related to jQuery.